# How can I solve this trigonometric problem

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, game-physics, trigonometry

I'm creating a game and want to solve this problem to make my game function.

Asin(RX) + Bcos(RX) + CX + D = 0
Find minimum X which is 0 or more and 1 or less.
A, B, C and R are variables.

I can use inverse trigonometric function, such as acos, asin and so on. But I want to make the calculation as accurate as possible.

I tried to make it simple with using trigonometric function formula, but I couldn't.

In more detail,
There are a rotating Box with move, and collision.

[White lines indicate the trajectories of one of the box corners. Red line is a collision.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnuAt.png)

I want to know exact time, when the corner hit the collision.

```
const Box = {
  Position: {
    x: 0,
    y: -300
  },

  Velocity: {
    x: 1500,
    y: 500
  },

  RotationSpeed: 19,
  DiagonalLength: 120
};

const Collision = {
  p1: {
    x: 50,
    y: -200
  },
  p2: {
    x: 1500,
    y: 300
  }
};

// **********************************************************
// Get a corner position of the BoX at provided time
// CornerID: 0-3 identify the edge
// time: Time 
// **********************************************************
getBoxCornerPosition(CornerID, time) {
  let addRadian = CornerID * Math.PI / 2;

  let posx =
    Box.Position.x + // Base position of the Box
    Box.Velocity.x * time + // Move distance of the Box
    Box.DiagonalLength * Math.cos(Box.RotationSpeed * time + addRadian); // Edge position

  let posy =
    Box.Position.y +
    Box.Velocity.y * time +
    Box.DiagonalLength * Math.sin(Box.RotationSpeed * time + addRadian);

  return [posx, posy];
}
```

I know that there could be no answer or multiple answer.
I want to know the minimum time when the edge hits collision, if there any answer.
Thanks.

Comment: So you already have a solution? Please post it. "*But I want to make the calculation as accurate as possible.*" - what exactly is not accurate enough?

Comment: No, I couldn't.
I could draw the situation what I want to solve. But don't know how to get the answer I want.
I realised that my question is too vague, so I added more detail.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Futurologist,  I was able to write code that works correctly.
The calculation way is somewhat different, but basically I followed the approach that he advised to me.

I added first part that checking whether not hit.
Thanks.

```
// Rotating and Moving box
let L = 180; // Box diagonal length
let M = {  // Box Move Speed
  x: 7,
  y: 3
}
let R = 0.30; // Box rotating speed
let P = { // Box position
  x: -700,
  y: -300
}

// Collision line: ax + by + c = 0
let a = 1;
let b = -2;
let c = 5;
```

```
// **********************************************************
// Get Box x, y according to given time
// This is for reference
// **********************************************************
getBoxPoint(time) {
  let Mx = M.x;
  let My = M.y;
  let Px = P.x;
  let Py = P.y;

  let x = L * Math.cos(R * time) + Mx * time + Px;
  let y = L * Math.sin(R * time) + My * time + Py;
  return [x, y];
}

// **********************************************************
// return greater than 0 hit time [] in ascending order
// return null when it never hit
// **********************************************************
GetHitTimes() {
  let result = checkParallel_HitRange();
  if (result === null) {
    console.log('Never Hit');
    return null;
  }
  if (result === undefined) {
    return calcHitTime(); // hit infinity times
  }

  let [minTime, maxTime] = result;

  if (maxTime < 0) {
    console.log('Never Hit in the future (hit in the past)');
    return null;
  }
  if (minTime < 0) {
    minTime = 0;
  }

  return calcHitTime(minTime, maxTime);
}

// **********************************************************
// Check if Box movement and Collision line is parallel
// Return:
// null: never hit
// undefined: hit positions are infinity
// [minTime, maxTime]: Range of potential collisions time
// **********************************************************
checkParallel_HitRange() {
  if (a / b === -M.y / M.x) { // is Parallel
    let distance = getColLineDistance(P.x, P.y);
    if (distance > L) { // Box and Collision are never hit
      return null;
    }
    // Collision points are infinity
    return undefined;
  }
  else {
    // Check range of potential collisions
    // x = Mx * time + Px
    // y = My * time + Py
    // D = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b)
    // +-L = (a * x + b * y + c) / D
    // +-L = ( (aMx + bMy) * time + aPx + aPy + c ) / D
    // +-LD = (aMx + bMy) * time + aPx + aPy + c
    // (aMx + bMy) * time = +-LD - aPx - aPy - c
    // time = (+-LD - aPx - aPy -c) / (aMx + bMy)
    let D = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);
    let time1 = (L * D - c - a * P.x - b * P.y) / (a * M.x + b * M.y);
    let time2 = (-L * D - c - a * P.x - b * P.y) / (a * M.x + b * M.y);
    console.log('Potential collison times are ' + time1 + ' - ' + time2);
    if (time1 < time2) {
      return [time1, time2];
    }
    return [time2, time1];
  }
}

// **********************************************************
// Get distance between given point from Collision line
// **********************************************************
getColLineDistance(x, y) {
  return Math.abs(a * x + b * y + c) / Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);
}


// **********************************************************
// Calculate and return hit time array with in given min-max time
// **********************************************************
calcHitTime(minTime, maxTime) {
  console.log('Min / Max ' + minTime + ', ' + maxTime);
  let Mx = M.x;
  let My = M.y;
  let Px = P.x;
  let Py = P.y;

  // line: ax + by + c = 0
  // x = L * Math.cos(R * time) + Mx * time + Px;
  // y = L * Math.sin(R * time) + My * time + Py;


  // a (  L * cos(R * time) + Mx * time + Px )   +   b ( L * sin(R * time) + My * time + Py ) + c = 0
  // aL * cos(R * time) + aMx * time + aPx + bL * sin(R * time) + bMy * time + bPy + c = 0
  // aL * cos(R * time) + bL * sin(R * time) + aMx * time + bMy * time + aPx  + bPy + c = 0
  // bL * sin (R * time)   +   aL *cos(R * time)   +   (aMX + bMY) * time   +   Pxa + Pyb + c = 0;

  // time = x / R
  // bL * sin (x)   +   aL *cos(x)   +   (aMX + bMY) / R * x   +   Pxa + Pyb + c = 0;

  let A = b * L;
  let B = a * L;
  let C = (a * Mx + b * My) / R;
  let D = a * Px + b * Py + c;

  // Asin(x) + Bcos(x) + Cx + D = 0;
  // asinθ + bcosθ = √a²+b² sin (θ + α)

  // f(x) = E * sin(x + Alpha) + Cx + D  ...   Fx(x, E, Alpha, C, D)
  // f'(x) = E * cos(x + Alpha) + C  ...   F_Prime(x, E, Alpha, C)
  let E = Math.sqrt(A * A + B * B);
  let Alpha = Math.acos(A / E);

  // Find all x when F'(x) = 0
  // f'(x) = E * cos(x + Alpha) + C = 0
  // cos(x + Alpha) = -C / E
  // x + Alpha = acos( -C / E) 
  // x = acos(-C / E) - Alpha  ...  getZeroOf_F_Prime(Alpha, C, E)

  let ZeroTime = getZeroTimeOf_F_Prime(Alpha, C, E);

  // Set range of check
  let endK;
  if (minTime === undefined) { // means have parallel move and hit infinity times
    endK = 20; // Limiting number of check
  }
  else {
    let startAdjust = (minTime - ZeroTime) / (2 * Math.PI);
    startAdjust = Math.floor(startAdjust);
    ZeroTime += startAdjust * 2 * Math.PI;
    endK = (maxTime - ZeroTime) / (2 * Math.PI);
    endK = Math.ceil(endK) + 1;

    if (endK > 20) {
      endK = 20;  // Limiting number of check
    }
  }

  // Get distance values in the range
  let distance = [];
  let checkTime;
  for (let loop = 0; loop < endK; loop++) {
    checkTime = (ZeroTime + 2 * Math.PI * loop) * R;
    distance[loop] = Fx(checkTime, E, Alpha, C, D);
    console.log(checkTime / R + ' : ' + distance[loop]);
  };

  let epsilon = 0.00001;
  let answerTime = [];
  let answerNum = 0;
  for (let loop1 = 0; loop1 < endK - 1; loop1++) {
    if (distance[loop1] * distance[loop1 + 1] < -1) { // hit moment shoud be between here

      // Newton method iterating
      let time = (ZeroTime + 2 * Math.PI * (loop1 + 0.5)) * R;
      time = Newton(time, E, Alpha, C, D);
      let prevTime = time;

      let loop2;
      for (loop2 = 0; loop2 < 5; loop2++) {
        time = this.Newton(time, E, Alpha, C, D);
        console.log('    iterate: ' + time / R);
        if (Math.abs(prevTime - time) < epsilon) {
          break;
        }
        prevTime = time;
      };
      if (loop2 >= 5) { // Usually iteration should convergence less than 5 times
        console.warn('Something wrong!');
      }
      console.log('Answer: ' + time / R);
      answerTime[answerNum] = time / R;
      answerNum++;
    }
  }

  return answerTime;
}

// **********************************************************
// Return the moment when the distance increase or decrease becomes zero
// **********************************************************
getZeroTimeOf_F_Prime(Alpha, C, E) {
  return Math.acos(-C / E) - Alpha;
}

// **********************************************************
// Return the distance
// **********************************************************
Fx(x, E, Alpha, C, D) {
  return E * Math.sin(x + Alpha) + C * x + D;
}

// **********************************************************
// 
// **********************************************************
F_Prime(x, E, Alpha, C) {
  return E * Math.cos(x + Alpha) + C;
}

// **********************************************************
// Newton Method iterating function
// **********************************************************
Newton(x, E, Alpha, C, D) {
  return x - Fx(x, E, Alpha, C, D) / F_Prime(x, E, Alpha, C);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have this square moving in the plane so that its centers moves with constant velocity along a straight line, while the square itself is rotating with a constant angular velocity around its center. Then, the motion of the red corner (and in fact of almost any point on the square) is described by equations like the following:

```
x(t) = r0*cos(R*t) - r0*sin(R*t) + v1*t + x0
y(t) = r0*sin(R*t) + r0*cos(R*t) + v2*t + y0
```

The red line is given by an equation that looks like this:

```
a*x + b*y = c
```

So the time of collision of the red corner of the square with the red line is when the following condition is satisfied (the red corner lies on the red line):

```
a*x(t) + b*y(t) = c
```

which written explicitly looks like this:

```
a*(r0*cos(R*t) - r0*sin(R*t) + v1*t + x0) + b*(r0*sin(R*t) + r0*cos(R*t) + v2*t + y0) = c
```

and by grouping the like-terms together:

```
r0*(a + b)*cos(R*t) + r0*(b - a)*sin(R*t) + (a*v1 + b*v2)*t + (a*x0 + b*y0 - c) = 0
```

or in an abbreviated form:

```
A*cos(R*t) + B*sin(R*t) + C*t + D = 0
```

where `A = r0*(a + b),   B = r0*(b - a),   C = a*v1 + b*v2,   D = a*x0 + b*y0 - c`
If we rename the argument `t = X`
we get exactly your equation

```
A*cos(R*X) + B*sin(R*X) + C*X + D = 0
```

There is no closed-form solution to this equation, you have to solve it numerically. In order to do that, you have to look at the function `Y = f(X)` where

```
f(X) = A*cos(R*X) + B*sin(R*X) + C*X + D
```

The geometric meaning of this function `f(X)` is that `f(t)` is the oriented distance between the the red point at time `t` and the red line, times a constant (more precisely `1/sqrt(a^2 + b^2)` ). In fact, if the coefficients `a,  b,  c` of the red line are chosen so that `a^2 + b^2 = 1`, then `f(t)` *is* exactly the oriented distance between the red point at time `t` and the red line.

To solve it, first we rewrite the function as follows

```
A_B = sqrt(A^2 + B^2)
f(X) = A_B*( (A/A_B)*cos(R*X) + (B/A_B)*sin(R*X) ) + C*X + D
```

Since `(A/A_B)^2 + (B/A_B)^2 = 1` there exists an angle `w` such that

```
cos(w) = A/A_B = A/sqrt(A^2 + B^2)
```

so we can set

```
w = arccos(A/A_B)
```

and thus

```
f(X) = A_B*( cos(w)*cos(R*X) + sin(w)*sin(R*X) ) + C*X + D 
     = A_B*cos(R*X - w) + C*X + D
```

First, you have to look at the derivative

```
f_prime(X) = - R*A_B*sin(R*X - w) + C
```

and find all of its zeros, if any (i.e. all `X` such that `f_prime(X) = 0`).

```
sin(R*X - w) = C / (R*A_B)
X = ( arcsin(C / (R*A_B)) + w +  2*k*pi ) / R  
X = (pi - arcsin(C / (R*A_B)) + w +  2*k*pi) / R
```

This works only when `-1 < C / (R*A_B) < 1`, otherwise there are no zeros.
The zeros of the derivative give all times `t=X` for which the tangent line to the white trajectory of the red corner is parallel to the red line. If there are zeros, the zeros split the real line of the `X` variable into intervals. You have to find for which interval `[X1, X2]`, where `f_prime(X1) = f_prime(X2) = 0`, you have that for the first time the function `f(X)` changes sign, i.e. you have to find when `f(X1) * f(X2) < 0` for the first time. Then take `X0 = (X1 + X2)/2` as a starting point and run Newton's method, iterating

```
X = X - f(X)/f_prime(X)
```

until `abs(f(X)) < epsilon` for your choice of epsilon, something like `epsilon = 0.00001'. The result should be the zero you are looking for.

If however the derivative has no zeros, then you can pick say X = 0 and again use Newton's method. I snippet of Python code for simple implementation of Newton's method may look like this

```
epsilon = 0.00001
X = X0
Y = f(X)
err = abs(Y)
while err > epsilon:
    X = X - Y / f_prime(X)
    Y = f(X)
    err = abs(Y)
```

This is the idea, but you have to work out the details, and revise the formulas I wrote to be sure that there are no mistakes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed advice!
I'll try it, and I'll post the working code here.

Comment: @HirokiSatoyoshi Sorry, I made some updates of my post,  I found some mistakes in the formulas.